# Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch

Tags: kotlin, generics, covariance

The code below shows the error. Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch **required**: `Response<BaseResponse<Any>>!` **found**:`Response<BaseResponse<RetriveUserInfoResponse>!>!`

```
`when`( mockIOnboardingService.validateCustomerIdentity(customerType.toLowerCase(), ValidateCustomerRequest(customerId, documentType, "243546", tyc)))
.thenReturn(Response.success(BaseResponse(payload = RetriveUserInfoResponse("+5689765432")))) //--> Here the error
```

This is the validateCustomerIdentity method

```
@POST(ApiConstants.bffOnboardingPath + ApiConstants.pathRetriveUserInfo)
    suspend fun validateCustomerIdentity(
        @Header(ApiConstants.headerXflowService) customerType : String,
        @Body body: ValidateCustomerRequest
    ): Response<BaseResponse<Any>>
```

As you can see it returns `BaseResponse<Any>`. Why Android Studio is showing me  `BaseResponse<RetriveUserInfoResponse>!` as an error

This is  the RetrieveUserInfoResponse data class

```
data class RetriveUserInfoResponse(
    @SerializedName("phone")
    val phone: String
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is that `Response.success(BaseResponse(payload = RetriveUserInfoResponse("+5689765432")))` produces a `Response<BaseResponse<RetriveUserInfoResponse>>`, which is not the same type (or a subtype) of `Response<BaseResponse<Any>>`.

You can fix it by casting `RetriveUserInfoResponse` to `Any`:

```
Response.success(BaseResponse(payload = RetriveUserInfoResponse("+5689765432") as Any))
```

Or alternatively by changing the return type of `validateCustomerIdentity()` to `Response<out BaseResponse<out Any>>`, which works because `Response<BaseResponse<RetriveUserInfoResponse>>` is a subclass of `Response<out BaseResponse<out Any>>`:

```
@POST(ApiConstants.bffOnboardingPath + ApiConstants.pathRetriveUserInfo)
suspend fun validateCustomerIdentity(
    @Header(ApiConstants.headerXflowService) customerType : String,
    @Body body: ValidateCustomerRequest
): Response<out BaseResponse<out Any>>
```